# Magento module on product detail page

Tags: magento, module

What module they use for color swatches, does any1 have any idea ?

http://www.harveynichols.com/mens/categories/designer-shirts/long-sleeved/s368022-gold-cutout-cube-print-shirt.html?colour=BLACK

Answer (score 0):

You may use Gala Color Swatches extension that is available for free on Magento Connect.